# Ubuntu 16.04: external USB DVD Drive us not recognised and can’t be mounted

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, usb-drive

I would like to mount a DVD Drive connected through a USB plug to my laptop, which is running Ubuntu 16.04.

`ls /dev/` yields the following results:
`dvd`, `dvdrw`, `cdrom`, `cdrw`

`sudo mount /dev/dvd /mnt/dvd` fails and prints `error: no medium found on /dev/sr0`

It is my understanding that the files mentioned above are only “links”, that point to `sr0`, hence I believe that the external drive is not being detected at all. Does that mean that I am missing a driver? If yes, please do tell me where I can download it.

I also have a laptop running Ubuntu 18.04, but neither `dvd` nor `dvdrw`, `cdrom`, `cdrw` show up on there.

I apologise if this is a duplicate question, but the other solutions I have found have not proven themselves helpful in this case.

Many thanks in advance.

Edit: providing output of `sudo lshw -C disk`:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWAWI.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
sudo lshw -C disk
```

that should list all drives including your optical drive - with "logical name".

Comment: Edited question

Comment: Sorry, my bad - "no medium found" already implied that the drive itself was there, so no point in looking for it. I know its a stupid question, but does the same medium in the same drive work on another computer and/or os?

Comment: It does not work on U16 nor 18, haven’t tried it on Windows nor MacOS

Comment: Would be interesting to have it tested on Windows. Thing is, that whenever I wasn't able to mount optical media over the past years, it was a hardware issue in every single case (either the drive or the media).
But thats only my personal experience - sorry that I cant help you further than that.